# Determine Postgresql datatype for a variable in Ruby, Python, or C++?

Tags: python, c++, ruby, postgresql

I've been using Ruby-pg so far as my interface for Postgres.  I have data that comes in on a socket to my Ruby program, which then needs to go into a Postgresql database.  Based on that data, a new table may be created, or new columns may be added to existing tables.  The data can be many different types, which brings me to my question: in Ruby, Python, or C++, is there a straightforward method to return the correct data type of the variable which can then be used to create/update table columns?

My Ruby pseudo-code would be:

```
var = 10ab30.234
datatype = type(var)
response = conn.exec("CREATE TABLE company(id_num #{datatype})")
```

Thanks!

Comment: In Ruby, how about just calling `.class`? Example: `"hello".class` will give you `String`.

Comment: Thanks @Casper, that's probably the best way to go.  I'll then make my own mapping to PostgreSQL data types.